# Extracting a string from a list of strings - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list: `messages = ['d h y u y r w u u r', 'y h w e u h e h d d']`.
The list can be longer than this, and contain strings of greater lengths.

How do I extract each string element of the list messages to be in their own list?
The spaces are important..I don't want to include them in the list.

**This is what I tried:**

```
newlist=[]
    for i in messages:
        for j in messages[0]:
            if j != ' ':
                newlist+=[j]
        print(newlist)
```

**This is what I got:**

```
['d', 'h', 'y', 'u', 'y', 'r', 'w', 'u', 'u', 'r']
['d', 'h', 'y', 'u', 'y', 'r', 'w', 'u', 'u', 'r', 'd', 'h', 'y', 'u', 'y', 'r', 'w', 'u', 'u', 'r']
```

I know that messages[0] would only look at the first index of messages, but when i try messages[i], I get an error that says:
<TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str>

Comment: `i` is an item in your list and not its index value

Comment: I think using `split()` would be easier.

Comment: i mean sure..but how do i do that?

Comment: `newlist = messages[0].split()` or `newlist = ''.join(messages[0].split())`

Comment: that just gives the first string twice

Answer (score 0):

What is the result you are trying to get?

If you want all letters in one list regardless of which one of the strings in the initial list they were from:

```
newlist=[]
for i in messages:
    for j in i:
        if j != ' ':
            newlist+=[j]
print(newlist)
```

gives

```
['d', 'h', 'y', 'u', 'y', 'r', 'w', 'u', 'u', 'r', 'y', 'h', 'w', 'e', 'u', 'h', 'e', 'h', 'd', 'd']
```

as in your first line "i" will be the string type entry of "messages" (not its index)

OR, if you want to keep the initial hierarchy:

```
newlist=[]
for i in messages:
    new_sublist = []
    for j in i:
        if j != ' ':
            new_sublist+=[j]
    newlist += [new_sublist]
print(newlist)
```

or, shorter

```
[sub_message.split() for sub_message in messages]
```

both give

```
[['d', 'h', 'y', 'u', 'y', 'r', 'w', 'u', 'u', 'r'], ['y', 'h', 'w', 'e', 'u', 'h', 'e', 'h', 'd', 'd']]
```

Comment: so now, how would i convert each of those lists back to strings?

Comment: as a by-hand way to make one big string  

`mylist = [['d', 'h', 'y', 'u', 'y', 'r', 'w', 'u', 'u', 'r'], ['y', 'h', 'w', 'e', 'u', 'h', 'e', 'h', 'd', 'd']]
result = ""  
for sublist in mylist:  
    for letter in sublist:  
        result += letter`  

or you could have directly gone from your initial list? i.e.  

`[sub_message.replace(' ', '') for sub_message in messages]`

Comment: i realize i asked my question incorrectly...what i meant was how do i convert each sublist, back to strings, and place them in their corresponding indexes according to the original list.

so for example:
[['d', 'h', 'y', 'u', 'y', 'r', 'w', 'u', 'u', 'r'], ['y', 'h', 'w', 'e', 'u', 'h', 'e', 'h', 'd', 'd']]

would become:
[['dhyuyrwuur'], ['yhweuhehdd']]

Comment: with what i wrote above you should get  ['dhyuyrwuur', 'yhweuhehdd']

you can simply modify this:


`[[sub_message.replace(' ', '')] for sub_message in messages]`
>> [['dhyuyrwuur'], ['yhweuhehdd']]